# Can you help me to build my MDX query

Tags: mdx, olap

This is my table : 
[image]

I want is to display messageBySession, imageBySession and videoBySession in Columns and UserDimension with dateDimension in Row. Is this possible ?

---

Edit

Here is my attempt at the query :

```
SELECT 
  {
    [Measures].[MessageBySession]
   ,[Measures].[ImageBySession]
   ,[Measures].[VideoBySession]
  } ON COLUMNS
 ,Hierarchize(CrossJoin([DateDimension].Children,[UserDimension].Children)) ON ROWS
FROM [SessionFacts];
```

I just need to Join DateDimension with UserDimension. i hope it can help someone.

Answer (score 0):

i found the query :

```
select {
    [Measures].[MessageBySession],
    [Measures].[ImageBySession],
    [Measures].[VideoBySession]
} ON COLUMNS,
Hierarchize(
    CrossJoin(
        [DateDimension].children,
        [UserDimension].children

    )
)
ON ROWS
from 
    [SessionFacts]
```

I just need to Join DateDimension with UserDimension. i hope it can help someone.